# When do I place an article before a verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs, articles

There is a product called "FUEL DOOR OPENER", lets say.

If it is responsible for opening and locking of a particular type of fuel door, is the following sentence correct?

> ACTUATOR that is responsible for **the** opening and locking of PUSH&PULL type fuel door.

When do I put, and not put the article before a verb? Is this even correct?

Also, I saw in some sentences, the article is placed before a noun too. In the above sentence, should "the" be placed before PUSH&PULL type fuel door?

Comment: You have a choice: Either '_...responsible for __the__ opening and locking __of__ the  PUSH&PULL type fuel door_'. Or '_...responsible for opening and locking the  PUSH&PULL type fuel door_'

Comment: The definite article before 'opening' is optional and there is little if any difference in the meaning with or without it. However the part of the sentence which says "...locking Push &Pull type fuel door is wrong. It should either be "...locking _the_ (or _a_ ) Push & Pull type fuel door" or "...locking Push & Pull type fuel _doors_".

Comment: Those verbs are gerunds, which function as nouns.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is never.

Articles are elements of noun phrases, not of verb phrases. Therefore they cannot be used with verbs, only with nouns.

1. This gizmo is responsible for opening the door.
2. This gizmo is responsible for **the** opening **of** the door.

In sentence (1), you have a verb phrase so you do not use an article. You know it is a verb phrase because it has a direct object: *the door*. We do not use prepositions to connect a verb’s object arguments to that verb. However, because this particular verb phrase is acting as the prepositional complement for the preposition *for*, some folks also refer to it as a gerund clause. In any event, articles are forbidden at the start of verb phrases like this.

In sentence (2), the all-important addition of the preposition *of* to connect the *-ing* word to the door following it means that that door is no longer the direct object of any verb, just the second of two nouns connected by a normal preposition. Because now it is a noun phrase, the article is allowed.